# log4net stuck & WCF

Tags: wcf, log4net, wcf-binding

I am using `log4net` in an enterprise system, the system have three tiers:

1. API
2. Internal Notifications
3. Integration to 3rd party: External Notifications

The layers talk each other via WCF (`wsHttpBinding`) and in each layer there is a log file.
When I run a test workflow, each tier executed his job but the logger did not write anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas:

1. In each tier, do you have a call to `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(...)`?  In most cases, people use an assembly attribute to do this in the AssemblyInfo.cs/Program.cs/Global.asax.cs/etc. but you can also just call it somewhere in your application startup routine.
   See this page ("When should I log my first message"): http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html
2. If you are using file-based logging, where are you trying to store the log files? - does the target directory exist, and does the user account that is running the tier have write permission to that folder?  For web apps, the user account is the App Pool identity, and for Windows Services, the user account is the Login that runs the service.  For console and windows apps, the user account may be the user that launches the app.

If all else fails you can turn on log4net internal debugging which might help:  http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html ("How do I enable log4net internal debugging")

Comment: I forgot to say that only one tier did not write to the log file

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?

Comment: Yes. some tier say "x" send synchronous call to "z" via "y" meaning while "z" send synchronous call to "x" while "x" did not exit its call. So the logger stuck with dead lock

Comment: Some tier say "x" send synchronous call to "z" via "y" **meaning while** "z" send synchronous call to "x" while "x" did not exit its call. So the logger stuck with dead lock since each public function starts with a `Logger.Debug("--- started")` and ends with `Logger.Debug("--- ended")`.

Comment: So you just removed your logging?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have configured log4net in the `App.config` files? A common mistake is to forget to call `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()` in the startup code of each tier. If that doesn't help, you need to show us your XML configuration.

Comment: I use a static instance in each tier and call `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()` in the static constructor

Comment: Some tier say "x" send synchronous call to "z" via "y" **meaning while** "z" send synchronous call to "x" while "x" did not exit its call. So the logger stuck with dead lock since each public function starts with a `Logger.Debug("--- started")` and ends with `Logger.Debug("--- ended")`.